# Filtering data from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an example element in the table:

> zxcdsa.com/photo-277590-30x24.jpeg
>
> zxcdsa.com/photo2-254654.png

I want to reject elements that in its name (el.src) have a string of characters from e.g. 30x30 to 350x350. How can I get this effect?
Filters elements using:

```
var newArray = someImages.filter(function (el) {
 const min = 400;
 const max = 700;
 const delimiter = 'x';
return el.width >= 400 ||
 el.class.indexOf('post-image') > -1 ||
 el.src.match( /\d+x\d+/ )[ 0 ]
   .split( delimiter )
   .every( ( number ) => {
     return number >= min && number <= max;
   });
 ....
});
```

This code does not work when `match()` cannot find the item.

Example:

- `29x200` => reject
- `200x220` => accept
- without `YYxYY` => accept

Comment: What is `string`, `min`, and `max`? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: string is el.src (in array)

Comment: The links are not working: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `.match()` doesn't find a match it returns `null`, not an array, so you can't index it with `[0]`. So you need to break that up into a variable assignment, test that it's not null, and the rest.

You can also use capture groups in the regexp to avoid having to call `split()`.

```
var newArray = someImages.filter(function (el) {
  return el.width >= 400 ||
    el.class.indexOf('post-image') > -1 ||
    ((m = el.src.match( /(\d+)x(\d+)/ )) && 
      [m[1], m[2]].every( number => number >= min && number <= max))
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you are making it hard for yourself.

Logically, split the string into array, then get the numbers and if they are divisible by 10 then allow and if not then disallow